# How re-format a Linux-USB in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, usb-flash-drive, formatting

#1. Say that I have an USB with some windows-files.
If I put the USB in a windows computer, the windows explorer will open and I can access the files.

#2. Say that I have an unformatted USB and put it in a windows computer.
Now a window will pop up saying that I need to format the unit before I can use it (and I can format directly from that windows).

#3. Say that I have created a bootable USB for instaling a linux distro, and then put the USB in a windows computer ... nothing happens, because windows don't recognize the linux file system.

How do I format that Linux-USB in windows so windows can use it?
If I open windows explorer, right click and choose manage, then open disk management - I normally can format an USB.
When I try to format the Linux-USB, the window from #2 above appear and interrupt the formatting.
If I try to format from that window, the windows appears again and interrupts itself in an endless loop.

If I open cmd, then diskpart, the same thing happens: an endless loop with the windows from #2.

How do I format a Linux-USB in windows?

(normally this isn't a problem, I just format the USB to FAT32 with gparted on a linux machine, but yesterday I was stuck with only a windows machine and only one Linux-USB and I needed an USB)

Answer (score 13):

### Format linux USB drive in Windows (not visible in file explorer)

Launch command prompt or Powershell, run the command `diskpart`.
The Diskpart command line application will open.

First, type `list disk` to show all of the disks connected to the PC. Now determine which of these is your Linux disk. You can usually identify it based on the sizes listed. You will want to be 100% sure of your selection here because the following commands will wipe ALL DATA from whichever disk you select.

Select the disk by using the command `select disk X` where X is the number of your disk from the previous command. Once you have selected your disk, use `clean` to remove all existing partitions.

Create a new partition with `create partition primary` and then mark it as `active`.
Finally, we can format the disk with `format fs=Fat32 quick`. Now your USB drive or SD card is ready to be used again.

For quick reference, here are all of the commands in order:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X
clean
create partition primary
active
format fs=Fat32 quick
```

Courtesy of https://www.jackofalladmins.com/admin%20adventures/knowledge%20bombs/format-linux-drive-windows/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't clean my disk in Windows 11 due to permission errors:

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: Access is denied.
```

And the Eventviewer had an entry:

```
Cannot zero sectors on disk \\?\PhysicalDrive1. Error code: \\?\Physical
```

I tried all recommended solutions (elevated command prompt, remove write protection with diskman, edit the registry etc). None worked.

Didn't want to use proprietary software, so I used Rufus to make a bootable usb drive, formatted as NTFS.

This is not intended use of Rufus, but it only took 2 minutes and it just worked so I'm happy :)

https://rufus.ie/en/

Comment: Thank you for this, it was the only option that worked for me, though I did use the "non bootable" formatting option in rufus portable.

Answer (score -1):

The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk.
The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.
The thumb drive is a larger one and fat32 will not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).